# Mac: change Finder shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, customization, keybindings

I want to reassign  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>  to a custom command, but Finder reserves it to open 'All My Files'.

I have looked around Preferences-Keyboard-Shortcuts, but the Finder shortcuts do not seem to be listed, so I cannot remove them.

Is there any way to remove the Finder shortcuts so I can assign them to what I want?

Many thanks,

Will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to assign 'All My Files' to something else [choose some complicated junk you'll never need]
You cannot remove a default, only reassign it.

Then you can add your chosen alternative with  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>  .
I used Documents to demonstrate, as it was just below

[image]

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts.
Finder [in fact no app] will not exist as a listed app until after you make the first shortcut for it.
To set up the first one, click + then select Finder from the drop menu; add your menu title, "All My Files" then your 'junk' key command.
After that, selecting the 'Finder' header from the list will auto-populate the app drop menu, making subsequent entries quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My problem is that I cannot find 'All My Files' (or the parent 'Finder') in the Shortcuts tab of the keyboard preferences.  What do you select in the left-hand pane in that tab (unfortunately obscured in your screenshot)?

Comment: It's App Shortcuts. Finder won't exist as an item in that list until you add the first key command for it. I'll update the answer.